# libGoogleAdMobAds 9.6.3 armv7 build error

Tags: ios, mobile, admob, ads, armv7

I'm trying to integrate the Google Mobile Ads SDK version 9.6.3 to my iOS app but I'm getting an armv7 build error on the iOS 7 APIs that the SDK is using. My app needs to support iOS 6 and above so my deployment target is 6.0. The release notes says that the SDK supports iOS 5 and above so I'm expecting that it should work.

Armv7 and armv7s are already in the valid architectures in the build settings of my project.

I also tried with their sample banner sample app but build is only successful for the simulator. The build error occurs when building for the device (I used ios 6 device)

Here are the logs for the sample banner app:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey", referenced from:
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForTopToBottomAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForBottomToTopAnimationPresentationWithTransitionContext:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
  "_UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey", referenced from:
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animateTransition:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
      -[GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation animationContextForRestoringAnimationToSavedState:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADViewControllerFullScreenSwipeAnimation.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADPercentDrivenUserInteractionAnimationController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **-ObjC in** the Build phase -> Other linker flag

Comment: -ObjC is already in the build settings. This does not occur with version 9.8